# If true, prove (01+0)*0 = 0(10+0)*, else provide a counter example.

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, formal-languages

Just by trying out a few examples, two regular expressions seem to be equivalent.

Here's my attempt at the proof.

We'll prove that $(01+0)^n0 = 0(10+0)^n \textrm{ }\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$(01+0)^{n+1}0 \\= (01+0)(01+0)^n0\\=(01+0)0(10+0)^n \textrm{ (by induction)}\\=(010+00)(10+0)^n\\=0(10+0)(10+0)^n\\=0(10+0)^{n+1}$$

Comment: Is + meaning exactly one or more ? In that case 01100 is in first set but not in the second because in the second set $1$ is always squeezed between zeros.

Comment: The proof looks fine to me. @zwim: + in the exponent has the meaning you describe, but here it stands for union/alternative. (01+0) is one out of 01 an 0.

Comment: @PeterLeupold ok, I would have noted that $\{01,0\}*0$ and $0\{10,0\}*$ then. anyway under these conditions I agree with the proof too.

Comment: You gave the induction step correctly, but you forgot to mention the initial step ($n = 0$), which is indeed trivial.